# Australia: Does this show a neutral wire?

Tags: wiring

New to home automation but based on initial research I’ve worked out that I need to determine whether the new flat is wired with a neutral wire to determine what options are available..
(Note this is in Australia...).

I’ve removed one of the wall panels and take the picture attached hoping someone would be able to give me an initial view!

[image]

Cheers,

Comment: Also, notice the switching on the red Active wire. New colours used these days

Answer (score 2):

Yup, the black wires in a terminal are neutral.

In general, where you have 2+ black wires, and they are in a separate terminal or the loop terminal of a switch, they are almost certainly neutral.

Make sure you're aware of what work you legally can and can't do in your area.